# java multithreading for incrementing and decrementing score

Tags: java, multithreading, increment, decrement

Working on a class assignment and I am struggling getting through it.

This needs to be thread safe and implement runnable.

I need to create 2 score objects that are initialized to a unique ID and an initial score of 100. Then need to create 20 threads and assign 5 threads to the incrementer and 5 threads to the decrementer of the first object and an additional 5 threads for each of the second object.

```
class ScoreRunnerDemo implements Runnable
{

private long id = 1;
private double score = 100;

Thread t1;
// Count()
{
    t1 = new Thread(this, "Runnable Thread")
            System.out.println("created thread " + t1);
    t1.start();
}

public void run ()
{
    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i<5; i++) {


            System.out.println("Printing the count " + i);
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            System.out.println("first increment thread 
 interrupted");

        }
    System.out.println("t1 is over");
}
}

public class ScoreRunner
{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //number of threads

    int n = 20;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        ScoreRunnerDemo object = new ScoreRunnerDemo();
        while (ScoreRunnerDemo.getScore < 200) {
            System.out.println("Thread: " + 
Thread.currentThread().getId() + " Score: " + ScoreRunner.());
        }
    }
}
```

please assist as I am unsure of what more I need.

The Score class is as follows:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Score
{
private long id;
private double score;
private DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###.##");

/**Grade
 * @param id
 * @param score
 */
public Score(long id, double score)
{
    this.id = id;
    this.score = score;
}

/** Method getId
 * @return
 */
public long getId()
{
    return id;
}

/** Method setId
 * @param id
 */
public void setId(long id)
{
    this.id = id;
}

/** Method getScore
 * @return
 */
public double getScore()
{
    return score;
}

/** Method setScore
 * @param score
 */
public void setScore(double score)
{
    this.score = score;
}

public synchronized void updateScore(double change)
{
    score += change;
    System.out.println("ID: " + id + "\t" + " Score: " + df.format(score));
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
 */
@Override
public String toString()
{
    return id + "\t" + "\t" + score;
}
```

}

Comment: Please reformat your code and provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - class `ScoreRunner` does not even seem to compile.

Comment: Please don't pass homework assignments on SO. A more directed question to explain the problem that you are facing will definitely benefit you.